# How to accept a string and an int using cin?

Tags: c++, cin

How to extract a string followed by an int, ignoring any whitespace? Any character after the integer number is not allowed. Something like this:
These input strings should give me string ("X") and int (1):

```
"X1"
"X1 " 
"X 1"
"X   1"
"X 1 "
"XX 1"
```

Also, I need to detect invalid characters after this integer "1", so these inputs should no be acceptable:

```
"XX 1d" // after 1 only ws should be OK
"XX 1 2" // after 1 only ws should be OK
```

Comment: Basically, cin>>string>>int, but this does not work.

Comment: @Sanyin Looking at your use-case, I would suggest using `getline` and parsing the string manually.

Comment: @Sanyin: That isn't legal code, and thus won't compile; is that what you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: @Sanyin Please post a [MCVE] showing exactly what _doesn't work_ with your code.

Comment: Typically you should read the entire line into a string and then parse the string.

Comment: `>>` is a really simple beast for really simple cases. ""XX 1d"" will be parsed as `string` "XX" and `int` 1 with the 'd' left in the stream for later because it isn't a valid integer digit. Similar failure would happen with "XX 3.14" 3 is a valid `int` and the ".14" stays in the stream. Out of range integers will also screw up. [Take a look at `std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) for a smarter string to integer convertor.

Comment: For your example inputs, you said they were "OK", but could you tell us the values grabbed and stored in the string and the int?

Comment: @user4581301 That's not really that helpful since `>>` doesn't work for "X1"

Comment: Not going to argue that. `>>` isn't the right tool for this job. It's just too stupid.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the few cases where I'd say a `regex` is by far your best solution.

You could use a regex like:

```
^\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\s*(\d+)\s*$
```

Then use [`regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) to check it. So for an input `string foo`:

```
smatch bar;

if(regex_match(foo, bar, regex{"^\\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\\s*(\\d+)\\s*$"})) {
    cout << "OK: " << bar[1] << '\t' << bar[2] << endl;
} else {
    cout << "not OK\n";
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/bf7NEb)